# topoplot in matlab: 2D visualisation of EEG data

Tags: matlab, eeglab

I want to make topomap using EEG data.
I used EEGLAB toolbox. 
It can make only interpolation form (figure 1).

[image]

I want to like this topomap (figure 2).

[image]

I already changed many option of EEGLAB's topoplot function. 
But, I couldn't find it. 
Is there any method of make that kinds of topomap using matlab?

Comment: Writing your own its always an option, you know the location of the points and their value